# IFFT and frequency information

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, ifft

Suppose there is a real signal `Amp_time` (Amplitude as a function of time) at Sample Rate `SampRate`.
I can transform it into frequency domain with

```
fftLength = length(Amp_time);

FT_freq = fft(Amp_time,fftLength); % signal as a function of frequency
FT_freq = FT_freq(1:fftLength/2);  % throw away symmetric part
```

and the corresponding frequencies:

```
freq = [0:fftLength-1].*(SampRate/fftLength); 
freq = freq(freq < SampRate/2);   % throw away symmetric part
```

To transform it back into time domain I simply use

```
Amp_time2 = ifft(FT_freq,'symmetric');
```

### Question

**But how about if I am changing the length of FT_freq?**

Suppose I want to reduce `length(FT_freq)` by averaging `FT_freq` to a coarser frequency vector (i.e. 10^3 instead of 10^5 frequencies).

```
[freq2,FT_freq2] = special_average(freq,FT_freq)   % reducing length of FT_freq
```

I don't think that it is possible to take the version above (because **how can Matlab possibly know to which frequency the signal is corresponding** now).

What am I missing?

Do I have to scale the coarse `FT_freq2` up again in order to get the right IFFT?
(bad in terms of memory, ...)

The reason I wanted to reduce the degrees of freedom of the Fourier Transform is to avoid having matrices with size of order `10^5 x 10^3` (FFTing every tenth of a second of some song) and thereafter **to compare freq-spectra/tones**.

Comment: Modifying the frequency bins by perhaps averaging elements into a lower length vector will have unintended side effects.  This would actually create a completely different signal.  If it is your goal to perform some sort of data compression, then adjusting the length of the FFT of the result is probably not the best course of action.

Comment: I wanted to compare different frequency spectra to identify recurring tones.